# How can you save a scene in JavaFX and recall it later with the same selection?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I've been searching the internet and stackoverflow for several hours for a solution to my question.

To the current problem:
I have a interface which makes it easier for the user to edit a SQLite database.
In my *main interface* the user has the possibility to set a filter for the display of the data with the help of several combo boxes.
If a new record is to be created, I open a new interface which allows the user to generate the data by just a few entries.
For this, I first close the *main interface* and then call the *create interface*.
However, if the user wants to cancel the creation process, the *main interface* should be loaded again with the previously made selection options and the *create inteface* should close.
Unfortunately I do not know how to achieve this.
I tried to accomplish this by imitating the last input of the user in the *main interface* initialize attempt. However, this is not possible because several combo boxes are required for the user selection and react completely dynamically to the previous selection.

I´m glad for every comment or helpfull link

Comment: So what should happen if the user does *not* cancel the creation process?

Comment: @DakshinamurthyKarra if the user does not abort the process, a datanbank update is executed and a select is executed on the new data and the interface is closed and the main interface from which the user came is reloaded and automatically populated with the new data. But thats not a problem.

Comment: The solution is not to close the previous stage, but just to make it invisible. On cancel of the operation, make that stage visible again.

Comment: something wrong in the code you are not showing ;) Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.